# Knockout 3.x: markup inside element referencing a named template is wiped out

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

In Knockout 2.x, one could write:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-template', foreach: elements }">
   <div class="placeholder">&lt;- these are the array elements.</div>
</div>
```

This way, a placeholder element could be appended to the rendered elements.

But, as I see, Knockout 3.0 changed this behavior: "placeholder" markup is just wiped out of the container element.

Is this intentional? Any workarounds?

One solution that I can immediately think of is adding "afterRender" to the template definition, but this has (according to my experiments with KO 3.0) a weird glitch: it doesn't fire for empty "elements" array.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Yes, the contents within the div would be removed. The best option I can think of is also on afterRender. But I don't understand "it doesn't fire for empty "elements" array" ?

Comment: @Ashwin If observable array linked to "foreach" section of template binding is empty, then "afterRender" won't fire for me.

Comment: Just to clarify .. the requirement is , you need to have the placeholder attached to all elements and also when there are no elements ?

Comment: @Ashwin yes, both cases - i.e. I want the placeholder to be present all the time.

Comment: One method is to create a placeholder template, then display the placeholder template the same you have done .. And also place it with "my-template".  In this way the placeholder template would be rendered when there is no template ( will be removed on the first item display ) and also will attached to the each array element.

Comment: I find the oddity to be that 2.x rendered the placeholder. Either way [several alternatives](http://jsfiddle.net/FLgPK/) available.

Comment: @Origineil thanks a lot for the fiddle! Can you please post it as an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comparing similar usages of templates to that of using the `foreach` option, I could not get the placeholder markup to render except for the specific case identified. As such, I'd assume that might not have been an intended usage.

Since the `foreach` option to the `template` binding doesn't provide anything that can't be replicated, one option would be to move the `elements` into the `data` option of a regular template and then "manually" provide the `foreach` markup either within a "container" element or containerless.

- Containerless option

  ```
  <script type="text/html" id="containerless-regular-template">
    <!-- ko foreach: $data  --> 
      <div data-bind="text:$data"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <div class="placeholder">&lt;- these are the array elements.</div>    
  </script>
  ```

If you want to get a little more fancy due to more dynamic requirements for the "placeholder", you could nest another template call at the end of the `foreach` markup within a containerless `if` binding. The outermost container would be limited but the contents would be dynamic.

```
 <script type="text/html" id="my-nested-template">
    <!-- ko foreach: $data.foreach -->
      <div  data-bind="text:$data"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko if: $data.template -->
      <div data-bind="template: { name: template.name, data: template.data }"></div>
    <!--/ko -->
</script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'my-nested-template', data: {foreach: [],  template: {name: 'another-template-name', data: {}}} }">
```

---

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FLgPK/)